# Android UI animation with native VS html cross-platform engine

Tags: android

I'm searching for a cross platform mobile development platform to start an application. 
I have tried some platforms like phone gap with jquerymobile. I'm capable of native android development. As I know native android is unable to support UI element with custom animations. I just found a nice app which have some smooth animations in it.

[Click Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toj.hungrynow&hl=en)

Does some one can Identify whether this app is made from native android or used with some cross-platform development tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript for HTML5 animations with cordova